# Adding an existing project to Solution Trouble shooting

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to add https://modernuicharts.codeplex.com/ WPF project into my solution.
I extracted the projects that was needed for wpf

```
Library - De.TorstenMandelkow.MetroChart.WPF
TestApplications - TestApplication.Shared
                 - TestApplicationWPF
De.TorstenMandelkow.MetroChart
```

I right clicked my current solutions and I went to Add -> Add Existing project and added the above projects.

When I set  TestAplicationWPF as start up Project, the Project runs completely fine.

My goal is to have a button which will display Modern UI Charts Interface in my other project called "WPF".

WPF - ViewModel

```
//Button Code
public MainWindow ShowModernUI()
{
    return new TestApplicationWPF.MainWindow();
}
```

It returns this error `A first chance exception of type 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll`

I checked the inner exception and it gave me `"Cannot find resource named 'PageContent'` which corresponds to TestAplicationWPF.MainWindow.xaml code

TestAplicationWPF.MainWindow.xaml

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding}" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource PageContent}" />
```

Page Content is from a resource Dictionary within TestAplicationWPF.

My attempt to fix the problem was to create a copy of the resource dictionary within my "WPF" project and it removed the error but nothing shows. May I ask how do I display the MainWindow from TestApplicationWPF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here's how to fix it:**

There are few issues with the library, there used to be a Nuget package but it has been unlisted so I'll show you how to compile and reference the library in your WPF app.

- download the file [`SourceAndTestApplications.zip`](http://modernuicharts.codeplex.com/) by clicking Download on the right
- extract the `MetroChart` folder somewhere and open the `MetroChart.sln` inside it

**If you are using VS2013 the following screen will appear:**

[image]

Nothing to worry about, just press OK and close the Migration Report it opened in IE

**Again, if you are under Windoww 8.1, the following will appear:**

[image]

Just press OK.

**Now there's something you need to do for the compilation to succeed:**

1. open Configuration Manager
2. choose Release Build
3. untick Build for `De.TorstenMandelkow.MetroChart`

[image]

**Building**

- right-click `De.TorstenMandelkow.MetroChart.WPF` project and build it
- when built, find the DLL in `MetroChart\De.TorstenMandelkow.MetroChart.WPF\bin\Release`

**Reference the project**

- create a new WPF project
- add a reference to `De.TorstenMandelkow.MetroChart.dll`

XAML :

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication3.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:metroChart="clr-namespace:De.TorstenMandelkow.MetroChart;assembly=De.TorstenMandelkow.MetroChart"
        xmlns:wpfApplication3="clr-namespace:WpfApplication3"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Width="525"
        Height="350">
    <Window.Resources>
        <wpfApplication3:MyObjectCollection x:Key="MyObjectCollection">
            <wpfApplication3:MyObject Category="Category1" Value="100" />
            <wpfApplication3:MyObject Category="Category2" Value="200" />
            <wpfApplication3:MyObject Category="Category3" Value="300" />
        </wpfApplication3:MyObjectCollection>
        <metroChart:ResourceDictionaryCollection x:Key="CustomColors">
            <ResourceDictionary>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Brush1" Color="#FF5B9BD5" />
            </ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Brush2" Color="#FFED7D31" />
            </ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Brush3" Color="#FFA5A5A5" />
            </ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Brush4" Color="#FFFFC000" />
            </ResourceDictionary>
            <!--  add more values with a different key  -->
        </metroChart:ResourceDictionaryCollection>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <metroChart:PieChart  Palette="{StaticResource CustomColors}"
      >
            <metroChart:PieChart.Series>
                <metroChart:ChartSeries DisplayMember="Category"
                                        ItemsSource="{StaticResource MyObjectCollection}"
                                        ValueMember="Value" />
            </metroChart:PieChart.Series>
        </metroChart:PieChart>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code-behind:

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApplication3
{
    /// <summary>
    ///     Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow() {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }

    internal class MyObject
    {
        public string Category { get; set; }
        public int Value { get; set; }
    }

    internal class MyObjectCollection : ObservableCollection<MyObject>
    {
    }
}
```

**Result**

[image]

See https://modernuicharts.codeplex.com/documentation for help.

Comment: Hello Aybe, this was ABSOLUTELY FANTASTIC. Couldn't have gotten any better. Thank you for taking the time and thoroughly explaining it step by step. Definitely made my day =)

Comment: Glad to see it helped!